# 質問掲示板の検索結果の表示の仕組みについて

Tags: 検索

ここだけでなく多くの質問掲示板で、検索した語から適応度の高いものを表示していますが、その適応のさせ方にはどのようなものがあるのでしょうか。
また、こちらではコードがある場合がございますが、それに関して他との違いはないのでしょうか？

Comment: 自然言語ならtf-idfは手頃です。簡単な仕組みの割に結構いい感じの結果が得られます。コードについては特定のトークンで分解するだけで良いのではないかと思います。